# Command is run before the previous one is finished

Tags: docker, powershell, dockerfile

Consider the following `Dockerfile`. It attempts to install Visual Studio Build Tools by downloading, installing, and then deleting the installer in a single `RUN` command.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest \
        -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe \
        -OutFile vs_buildtools.exe; \
    .\vs_buildtools.exe --nocache --norestart --quiet --wait \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041; \
    Remove-Item -Path vs_buildtools.exe
```

When building the image, the installer is downloaded and started, and then the installer is attempted deleted before the installation is done! This of course generates an error:

```
Remove-Item : Cannot remove item C:\vs_buildtools.exe: The process cannot
access the file 'C:\vs_buildtools.exe' because it is being used by another
process.
```

The build continues after the error, completing the installation.

Why is `Remove-Item` executed before `.\vs_buildtools.exe` is done?

If I take `Remove-Item` out into its own `RUN` command, it works fine:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest \
        -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe \
        -OutFile vs_buildtools.exe; \
    .\vs_buildtools.exe --nocache --norestart --quiet --wait \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041
RUN Remove-Item -Path vs_buildtools.exe
```

Comment: Docker runs commands writing in one line consecutively, so when you put it all of your command Docker runs it without awarnes if it's finished or not.

Comment: @ZemmouriTarek `.vs_buildtools.exe` is not executed until `Invoke-WebRequest` is done, so I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @ZemmouriTarek That's not correct

Comment: If vs_buildtools.exe runs in the background, you'd have to use start-process -wait, or wait for it some other way.

Comment: @js2010 The `--wait` argument of `vs_buildtools.exe` should take care of that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#layout-command-and-command-line-parameters

Comment: It seems like it doesn't, since the accepted answer has "cmd /c", which is another way to wait for a process to finish.

Comment: @HansKilian A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. Using docker build users can create an automated build that executes several command-line instructions in succession. This page describes the commands you can use in a Dockerfile . Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#:~:text=A%20Dockerfile%20is%20a%20text,can%20use%20in%20a%20Dockerfile%20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to use `cmd` instead of `powershell`.

Both the following approaches work:

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest \
        -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe \
        -OutFile vs_buildtools.exe; \
    cmd /c "vs_buildtools.exe --nocache --norestart --quiet --wait \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041"; \
    Remove-Item -Path vs_buildtools.exe
```

```
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN curl -SL https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe -o vs_buildtools.exe \
    && call vs_buildtools.exe --nocache --norestart --quiet --wait \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64 \
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041 \
    && call del /q vs_buildtools.exe
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
```